# how to add a table to a page with header and footer using itext 7

Tags: java, pdf, itext7

i need to add a table in a specific position and be repeated in all pdf pages without interference with header and footer 
this is my code

```
PdfEventHandler handler = new PdfEventHandler(header, x,y);
pdf.addEventHandler(PdfDocumentEvent.START_PAGE, handler);
Table table = new Table(getcolumnsWidth(pdfColumns, tableWidth));
String line = br.readLine();
process(table, line, true);
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    process(table, line, false);
}
br.close();
document.add(table);
```

with

```
public class PdfEventHandler implements IEventHandler {

    private String header;
    private int x,y;

    public PdfEventHandler(String header,int x , int y) {
     this.header =header;
     this.x = x; this.y =y;
    }

    @Override
    public void handleEvent(Event event) {
        PdfDocumentEvent docEvent = (PdfDocumentEvent) event;
        PdfDocument pdfDoc = docEvent.getDocument();
        PdfPage page = docEvent.getPage();
        PdfCanvas pdfCanvas = new PdfCanvas(page.newContentStreamBefore(), page.getResources(), pdfDoc);
        Rectangle area = page.getPageSize();
        int pageHeight = (int) area.getHeight();
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(pdfCanvas, pdfDoc, area);

        canvas.showTextAligned(header, x, y, TextAlignment.CENTER);
    }
}
```

this is the result pdf file 
[image]

Comment: https://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/page-events/clone-page-events-headers-and-footers

Comment: Probably your `x` and `y` are wrong?

Comment: the problem is that i can define the position for the table, if i set a fixed position the table will appear only on first page

Answer (score 0):

That's very unclear what you try to achieve, so I've made several assumptions.

First: you create your pdf from scratch (there is no source file).
Second: you want to place a table on each page (onto specific area) and the table should not interfere with the other content.

So how to place a table (or another element) on each page?
One can use an event handler for it. Please look at the next example: https://github.com/itext/i7js-examples/blob/develop/src/test/java/com/itextpdf/samples/sandbox/events/TableFooter.java
There a table is added as a footer once a new page is created.

As for you code I believe that you should have used the showTextAligned which requires a page number:
http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/itext7/latest/com/itextpdf/layout/RootElement.html#showTextAligned-com.itextpdf.layout.element.Paragraph-float-float-int-com.itextpdf.layout.property.TextAlignment-com.itextpdf.layout.property.VerticalAlignment-float-

Answer (score 0):

You can use `table.setRelativePosition(0, 0, 0, 0)` to place your table content after the repeated headers on your pdf